# Email users, unless they appear in list

Tags: 2010, email, alert

I have a series of forms which users are required to fill in by a certain date. 
5 days before this date I'd like to send out an email reminder to those who have not completed it. 
Is there a way of setting a workflow to email only the ones who haven't filled it in. All the users expected to fill it in will be part of their own sharepoint group, but I do not want to remind the ones who have done it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard part is to get a list of all users.

One way could be to generate an entry in the list for all users, start the workflow which waits until deadline minus 5 days, checks if certain fields are filled and if not email the user.

Another option would be to create a separate list with all the users, start the workflow on each item here and then do a lookup for an item in the real list and send out an email if it's not there